# Seeking Advice on Using PostgreSQL Triggers for Supabase Authentication in Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I've been working on a Supabase project that involves authentication. My database structure includes a `Profiles` table that is linked to the `auth.users` table in Supabase. The `Profiles` table serves as a central table that other tables reference via foreign keys. For more context on my database architecture, you can check this [Discussion](https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/17115#discussioncomment-6900929).

I encountered an issue with Row-Level Security (RLS) when trying to insert a new row into the `Profiles` table upon user sign-up. The problem was that the user needs to be signed in to insert into the `Profiles` table, but they aren't signed in yet during the sign-up process.

To solve this, I used PostgreSQL triggers. I created a function that inserts a new row into the `Profiles` table whenever a new user is added to the `auth.users` table. Here's the function definition:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_profile()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO "Profiles" (user_id) VALUES (NEW.id);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I then set up a trigger to call this function whenever a new row is inserted into the `auth.users` table.

Here's the relevant part of my sign-up code in my Next.js 13 project:

```js
  const handleSignUp = async () => {
    const response = await supabase.auth.signUp({
      email,
      password,
      options: {
        emailRedirectTo: `${location.origin}/auth/callback`,
      },
    });
  
    // Log the sign-up response
    console.log("Sign-up response:", JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  
    if (response.data && response.data.user) {
      // Log the identities array
      console.log("Identities array:", JSON.stringify(response.data.user.identities, null, 2));
  
      if (response.data.user.identities && response.data.user.identities.length > 0) {
        console.log("Sign-up successful!");
      } else {
        console.log("Email address is already taken.");
        const signInResponse = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
          email,
          password,
        });
  
        if (signInResponse.error) {
          console.error("An error occurred during sign-in:", signInResponse.error.message);
        } else {
          console.log("Successfully signed in existing user!");
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.error("An error occurred during sign-up:", response.error?.message);
    }
  
    router.refresh();
  };
```

Interestingly, when I manually created a user in the `auth.users` table via SQL, the trigger worked as expected. However, when I tried to sign up a user through my Next.js 13 project, not only did I encounter the following error message, but the new account in `auth.users` also wasn't created:

```
An error occurred during sign-up: Database error saving new user
```

Is this a good solution to the problem I was facing? Are there any potential issues or better approaches that I should consider? Why might the trigger work in one context but not the other?

Thank you for your time and insights!

Best regards,
Vladimir

Comment: So the nice thing about triggers is that if anything fails, the entire database transaction causing the trigger will also roll back, which means the database integrity is protected. It seems like there might be some issues in your `profiles` table. Can you share the table definition of it?